# How to find all shared files in a SourceSafe repository

Tags: vb.net, visual-sourcesafe

We want to migrate a repo/database from VSS->TFS but have a number of files which are shared between VSS projects. I'm told TFS will migrate these as multiple copies which isn't useful, so we need to find all the shared files and update VSS so they are put in a shared code library or something instead.

But how can I find all the files which are shared (not branched), it's a large repo?

I did find this on CodeProject: http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/545812/Visual-SourceSafe-automation-to-get-shared-referen

It appears to be just what I need but I don't know VB and there are no instructions... is it an application I can run or a function I have to call somehow? If anyone can work a complete solution around this you'd be my hero (and I will award a healthy bounty as a thankyou if that's allowed)

Comment: [SourceSafe Reporter claims to be able to do it.](http://www.source-safe.com/)

Comment: I probably can't get authorisation to buy anything easily, but it's handy to know in case we run into a brick wall... the cost could be less than the time we'd spend on it otherwise.